# Matrix multiplication in a for loop

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

When the following code is run in R, an error message pops up:

"Error in Xt[i, ] <- F * Xt[i - 1, ] + V : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Appreciate your help.

```
X=matrix(rnorm(6),100,6)
n = nrow(X)

F =  diag(1,6,6); F[1,4] = F[2,5] = F[3,6] = 1

#create process & measurement noises (standard deviation)
W = diag(rnorm(1,0,0.01),6,6) 
V = diag(rnorm(1,0,0.02),6,6) 

#create and init Xt and Yt matrices
Xt = matrix(NA, nrow=n+1, ncol=6)
Yt = matrix(NA, nrow=n, ncol=6)
Xt[1,] = X[1,]

#test: 
F * Xt[1,] + V #this is fine!!!

#before entering the loop:
for (i in 2:3)
{
  Xt[i,] = F * Xt[i-1,] + V #BUT this is not!!!
  Yt[i,] = Xt[i,] + W
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the dimensions:
You define

```r
Xt[1,] = X[1,]
```

which gives you a `6x1-matrix`. Your next step is calculating

```r
F * Xt[1,] + V
```

Since `F` and `V` are of dimension `6x6` this yields a new `6x6-matrix`. Check with

```r
dim(as.matrix(X[t,1]))
dim(F)
dim(V)
```

Now `Xt` itself is of dim `101x6`, therefore `Xt[n,]`, which is a little bit unintuitively, gives a transposed `6x1` object. So, inside your loop you tried to assign an object

```r
F * Xt[i-1,] + V
dim(F * Xt[i-1,] + V)   # this gives 6x6
```

to

```r
Xt[i,]
dim(as.matrix(Xt[i,]))  # this gives 6x1
```

So your dimensions don't fit. I hope this answers your question.

I have one annotation:

```r
F * Xt[1,] + V
```

The multiplication `F*Xt[1,]` is an element-wise multiplication not the classical matrix-vector-multiplication. If you want to perform an `A*b` multiplication with `mxn`-matrix `A` and `nx1`-vector `b` you have to use `%*%` instead. In this case, `V` has to be of dimension `mx1`.

Comment: Thanks Martin -- got it resolved: V/W as vectors and %*% as operator.